# How to get SOCKS5 capable application proxied through OpenVPN without running everything through VPN on Gnome 3

Tags: networking, fedora, openvpn, gnome3, socks5

How can I selectively tunnel by application in Gnome using a remote OpenVPN server or use the arbitrary application's built-in SOCKS5 proxy support to connect to a local "translation" server that forwards SOCKS packets as OpenVPN packets.

```
Blacklisted Applications -> remote OpenVPN server -> internet
```

and

```
Whitelisted Applications -> internet
```

OR

```
Application -> local SOCKS5 server -> remote OpenVPN server -> internet
```

or maybe I'm over thinking it. All I know is I can't tunnel everything through the VPN, but I also cannot let certain applications through without pushing through the OpenVPN server.

Comment: You mean you want e.g. firefox to use a SOCKS proxy? In that case, just use ssh.

Comment: @TNierath I have edited my post in attempt to clarify what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. If an app allows to use a proxy then you can use a proxy server for that app... If by default you access the internet with your local connection but are also connected to a VPN, then your machine can access services from hosts on that network, including proxy servers. But all of this happens on the app level, with special configuration settings. I guess it should be possilbe to put all blacklisted apps inside a container/VM, but that's overkill?

Comment: So how would I use split tunneling?

Comment: Did you set up the OpenVPN connection? The default should not change the default routing table entry, so everything except for the private network connections goes over your standard internet connection.

Comment: I used NetworkManager to set it up, but yes.

Comment: I can't help you with the NM setup, you should find out if everything is tunnled or it it's only a connection to the remote private network. If the latter and if you want to use SOCKS for some clients, then just use ssh, that's all you need for SOCKS.